# Vscode PHP Server extension not working after brew upgrade to php 7.4 in OSX?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

After upgrading from 7.3 to 7.4 using brew in OSX Catalina, the PHP Server extension in VS Code no longer works. Selecting "PHP SERVER: Serve Project' just shows the php code in the browser as a text file. It no longer starts the PHP server.

I followed these instructions:

```
brew install php@7.4
brew link --force --overwrite php@7.4 
brew services start php@7.4 
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin:$PATH" 
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/sbin:$PATH"
```

Upon completion, the command "php -v" in the terminal gave the correct version, 7.4. I don't know how to set PHP Server to use the upgrade? Adding the following paths (determined from running "which php" and "php -ini" in the terminal) to vscode's settings.json didn't fix the situation:

```
"phpserver.phpConfigPath": "/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php.ini",
"phpserver.phpPath": "/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin/php",
```

Once I uninstalled running "brew uninstall php@7.4", the PHP Server worked again. I would like to be able to use PHP 7.4. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To remedy the situation, I switched to using XAMPP as my php server, with my Vscode workspace moved to XAMPP's htdocs folder.

I also switched from using the Vscode "PHP Server" extension to the "Open PHP/HTML/JS in Browser" extension, setting the extension's "Document Root Folder" setting to "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs" (without quotes), so I can just right-click on an php page in Vscode and open it in the browser, as I did with PHP Server.

So that my php pages autoload on change, I am using the browser "Live Server" plugin (requires the vscode Live Server extension) with the Actual Server Address set to "http://localhost", and VS Code's Live Server Address set to the default "http://127.0.0.1:5500/" (found by clicking on "Go Live' in the lower right of Vscode).

In conclusion for php with Vscode, I am now using XAMPP, "Open PHP/HTML/JS in Browser" extension, and the browser "Live Server" plugin.